# How to extract xml soap body from xml envelope using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xml, soap, kissxml

How to extract xml soap body from xml envelope using objective c?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:c="http:************************" 
xmlns:soap="http://********************" 
xmlns:n1="http://**************" xmlns:n2="http:***********">
<soap:Header>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <n1:GetDeviceConfiguration id="o0" c:root="1">
        <n1:request>
            <n2:Header>
                <n2:DeviceName>Tester Phone</n2:DeviceName>
                <n2:DeviceIpAddress>***********</n2:DeviceIpAddress>
                <n2:AppVersion>1.2</n2:AppVersion>
                <n2:RequestTime>2018-01-10T10:10:27</n2:RequestTime>
                <n2:MessageId>******************</n2:MessageId>
            </n2:Header>
            <n2:Body>
                <n2:LastUpdate>2017-08-06T15:34:00</n2:LastUpdate>
            </n2:Body>
        </n1:request>
    </n1:GetDeviceConfiguration>
</soap:Body>
```

From this xml i want to extract the soap:Body using objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the soap Body using XMLParser.

First convert your xml into NSData and call the parser to parse it.

```
    //converting into NSData
    NSData* data = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //initiate  NSXMLParser with this data
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    //setting delegate
    parser.delegate = self;

    //call the method to parse
    BOOL result = parser.parse;

    parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true;
```

Now, you need to implement the NSXMLParser delegate into your class.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *)attributeDict {
currentElement = elementName;
NSLog(@"CurrentElementl: [%@]",elementName);
```

}

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
NSLog(@"foundCharacters: [%@]",string);
```

}

You will find the value under key of your xml.

Do not forget to add **NSXMLParserDelegate** into your class interface.